# Compare Two column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
|  A    | B | C |
|-------|---|---|
| ['1'] | 1 | 1 |
|['1,2']| 2 |   |
| ['2'] | 3 | 0 |
|['1,3']| 2 |   |
```

if the value of B is equal to A within the quotes then C is 1. if not present in A it will be 0. Expected output is:

```
|  A    | B | C |
|-------|---|---|
| ['1'] | 1 | 1 |
|['1,2']| 2 | 1 |
| ['2'] | 3 | 0 |
|['1,3']| 2 | 0 |
```

Like this I want to get the dataframe for multiple rows. How do I write in python to get this kind of data frame?

Comment: Please post the minimum code required to reproduce the problem

Comment: Why are the values in the lists as one string?

Comment: It was extracted from a json file in pandas column

Comment: @N2M - what is `print (df.A.head().tolist())` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values in `A` are strings use:

```
print (df.A.tolist())
["['1']", "['1,2']", "['2']", "['1,3']"]

df['C'] = [int(str(b) in a.strip("[]'").split(',')) for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
print (df)
         A  B  C
0    ['1']  1  1
1  ['1,2']  2  1
2    ['2']  3  0
3  ['1,3']  2  0
```

Or if values are one element lists use:

```
print (df.A.tolist())
[['1'], ['1,2'], ['2'], ['1,3']]

df['C'] = [int(str(b) in a[0].split(',')) for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
print (df)
       A  B  C
0    [1]  1  1
1  [1,2]  2  1
2    [2]  3  0
3  [1,3]  2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

My code:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df
'''
         A  B
0    ['1']  1
1  ['1,2']  2
2    ['2']  3
3  ['1,3']  2
'''

(
    df.assign(A=df.A.str.replace("'",'').map(eval))
    .assign(C=lambda d: d.apply(lambda s: s.B in s.A, axis=1))
    .assign(C=lambda d: d.C.astype(int))
)
'''
        A  B  C
0     [1]  1  1
1  [1, 2]  2  1
2     [2]  3  0
3  [1, 3]  2  0
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['B'].astype(str).isin(df.A), 1,0)
```

basically you need to transform column b to string since column A is string. then seek for column B inside columnA.

result will be as you are defined.